# ListView item won't change its backgroundColor in onCreate, but it does onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I have two lists, a long and a short one.
Only the long one will be displayed, and the list items of the long list that are also in the short list should get a blue backgroundColor.
As you can guess, this doesn't work.

Apart from that I can change the backgroundColor of an item onItemClick.
(This works)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_couple_file);

List<String> longList = new ArrayList<String>();
longList.add("A");
longList.add("B");
List<String> shortList = new ArrayList<String>();
longList.add("A");

//        display longList
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, longList);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

//        look for common elements
    for (int i = 0; i < longList.size(); i++) {
        if (shortList.contains(longList.get(i))) {
            View view = listAdapter.getView(i, null, list);
//        should change the item view's color, but it doesn't
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        }
    }

    registerClick();
}

private void registerClick() {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
 //       however, this does change the item view's color    
viewClicked.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
    }  
}
```

I know that the if-statement works, I have cast view to a TextView and showed its text in a toast.

While there may be completely other options to do this, I would like to know why the backgroundColor of the "A" item doesn't change onCreate while it should (it doesn't crash either), although it works in the onItemClickListener.

**Edit:**
I have switched the position of the setAdapter part and the if-statement (as I have it in my original code logically), and used setBackgroundResource as android studio suggests, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think it is because it is using the background color of the simple_list_item_1. Which isn't set until you run your adapter. Try to have it change it while being processed int the adapter. Or you can find out which items you want to change and do it after the adapter has displayed the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**kindly move your this code::**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < longList.size(); i++) 
 {
       if (shortList.contains(longList.get(i)))
       { 
            View view = listAdapter.getView(i, null, list); 
            // should change the item view's color, but it doesn't 
           view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
       }
  }
```

**To after 'registerClicks()':**

```
      registerClick();

      for (int i = 0; i < longList.size(); i++)   
      { 
           if (shortList.contains(longList.get(i))) 
           { 
                View view = listAdapter.getView(i, null, list);
                 // should change the item view's color, but it doesn't 
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            }
     }
```

Actually the problem is that, you are calling the background change before actually listing your list view. So it is not getting views of child to which you want to change background colour.

**EDITED:**

Use this code:

```
  list.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           for (int i = 0; i < longList.size(); i++) {
               if (shortList.contains(longList.get(i))) {
                   list.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(
                           getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
               }
           }
       }
   });
```

Why I am using ".post()", its because without this we are fetching its view but your list is not created yet.

Thanks and Happy Coding!!

Comment: I changed the order of my code as you can see in my edited post, and also tried what you suggested, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Hey Dennis, I solved your problem. see my updated code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem, although I don't fully understand why it is needed.

Comment: Actually in previous code, list is not prepared and we are trying to fetch it's child so it not rendering properly. That's why we use this code.it will automatically called when list is completely prepared.

Answer (score 1):

Using, list.getchildat(), specifying the index within the parenthesis, should work.